# Custom list view based on current URL

Tags: list-view, asp.net

I would like to create a list view in a template site si that when a subsite is created by using that template takes the subsite url, extracts the name (e.g. in https://...sharepoint.com/sites/project1 gets project1) and uses project1 as filter (show all items that have project1 in columnX).

Obviously, it should automatically use project2 when the subsite is https://...sharepoint.com/sites/project1 gets project1

I tried to edit a custom view but I am completely new to ASP

Any clue?

Comment: Can you provide additional information what is your code and in which place you are looking for that change.